# Android Email Application: Open a Message directly

Tags: android

By looking at the link 
[Downloading sent mails from Yahoo, Gmail and Hotmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001254/downloading-sent-mails-from-yahoo-gmail-and-hotmail)
is it possible to invoke or call Gmail and open a message programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you looking for.

```
    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.email");
    startActivity(intent);
```